# Number of different rankings of $n$ people

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a ranking of $n$ people, possibly with ties. For example, if there are two people, the possibilities are $1>2$, $2>1$, and $1=2$. If there are three people, the possibilities are $1>2>3$ and permutations, $1>(2=3)$ and permutations, $(1=2)>3$ and permutations, and $1=2=3$.

Let $a_n$ denote this number. So $a_2=3$ and $a_3=13$. Prove that $1.4^{n-1}\cdot n!\leq a_n\leq 1.5^{n-1}\cdot n!$.

Comment: The series is http://oeis.org/A000670  I don't see a simple formula, but there are lots of references.